# Plugin privelages for "editors"

Tags: plugins, users, user-roles

I have a few plugins installed in wp that appear in the submenu of the dashboard. I want users with the "editor" role to only have access to specified plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager)

But I think it might be better if you create a new role, then copy roles from "Editor" using the plugin above, and then allow the new role to access those plugins you wanted.